# Picasso circular transformation with border

Tags: android, transformation, picasso

Trying to to apply a circular transformation with a border, but the size of the border is not being respected and the antialias does not work either.

I want to create a circular transformation with given color and borderWith.

This is my transformation class:

```
public static class CircleTransformation implements Transformation {

    @ColorInt
    private final int borderColor;

    private final float borderRadius;

    public CircleTransformation() {
        this.borderColor = -1;
        this.borderRadius = -1;
    }

    public CircleTransformation(@ColorInt final int borderColor, final float borderRadius) {
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
        this.borderRadius = borderRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
        // if the source bitmap is null we can't do anything
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        final int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        final int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        final Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        final float r = size / 2f;

        // if border is configured we draw it
        if (borderRadius != -1) {
            // Prepare the background
            final Paint paintBg = new Paint();
            paintBg.setColor(borderColor);
            paintBg.setAntiAlias(true);

            // Draw the background circle
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paintBg);

            // Draw the image smaller than the background so a little border will be seen
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r - borderRadius, paint);

        } else {
            // Draw the image as a circle
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
        }

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("HardCodedStringLiteral")
    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle(color=" + borderColor + ",radius=" + borderRadius + ")";
    }
}
```

To display the image:

```
val borderColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, borderColorRes)

//borderRadiusRes = 2dp
val borderRadius = context.resources.getDimension(borderRadiusRes)

PicassoProvider.with(view.context)
                            .load(url)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                            .transform(PicassoProvider.CircleTransformation(borderColor, borderRadius))
                            .into(view)
```

The end result is the following:

[image: Result]

As you can see above, the red border is not smooth at all, and the border does not have 2dp.
What am I missing here?

Comment: if you dont mind you can use round image view or circle image view for this border color size

Comment: I would like to achieve this without the need of importing 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method `resizeDimen` or `resize` from Picasso solved the issue.

Usage:

```
PicassoProvider.with(view.context)
                            .load(url)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                            .resizeDimen(R.dimen.image_size_width,R.dimen.image_size_height)
                            .transform(PicassoProvider.CircleTransformation(borderColor, borderRadius))
                            .into(view)
```